# Ruby on Rails Spree Jquery - Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, spree

I have installed spree to my production server in digitalocean with using nginx, pgsql and rvm. Everything was OK. The project was working properly in my localhost:3000. I added dummy products by using `rake db:bootstrap` I get Card expiration date error but the products created properly.

My local screenshot:
[image]

My production screenshot:
[image]

I m sure about product_descriptions are not empty. When the database was empty I got same error again. 
I cant see any product in my view.

Anybody know how can I solve that error:

```
 dotdotdot: No element found for "#home-slider .product-description".
```